# How to randomly assign to treatment groups for online web study?

Tags: javascript, random, variable-assignment

I am conducting a web study where participants will be proportionately and randomly assigned to treatment groups in the form of different web pages.  I have a study landing page where I plan to assign participants to different treatment groups by directing them to different pages based on a random integer within the range of the sample size.  For example, for a n=100 study, this code might look like:

```
/// Function for randomly shuffling array
function shuffle(array) {
  array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
}

const STUDY_LEN = 100;  /// Study n
const arr_0 = new Array(STUDY_LEN/2).fill(0);  /// Create array for treatment 1
const arr_1 = new Array(STUDY_LEN/2).fill(1);  /// Create array for treatment 2

const arr_assign = arr_0.concat(arr_1);  /// Concatenate treatment arrays for entire study assignment
arr_shuffle = shuffle(arr_assign);  /// Randomize order of array

for (i = 0; i < STUDY_LEN-1; i++){
  if (arr_shuffle[i] == 0){
    //// Change hyperlink to web page for treatment 1
}
  else{
    //// Change hyperlink to web page for treatment 2
  }
}
```

How can I store these variables (mainly the shuffled assignment array) across multiple visits to the web page so that I assign participants to each treatment equally (50 participants in treatment 1, 50 participants in treatment 2)?  My solution doesn't seem like a very robust way to randomly assign users to different treatments, so I'm open to any/all suggestions.

Comment: You might try `shuffle()`ing multiple times for a better random distribution. As you always have 50 (0)-50 (1) there no chance of group skewing ie. `arr_assign.reduce((t,n)=> t+n)` will always be 50

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to get the test type from a server if you want to randomly but equally distribute the tests

```
function getTestType () {
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    // This will ensure that the maximum number of occurences for the test A will be 50.
    if (getNumberOfOccurencesOfTestA() < 50) {
      return true; // Test A
    }
  }

  // This will ensure that the maximum number of occurences for the test B will be 50.
  if (getNumberOfOccurencesOfTestB() < 50) {
    return false; // Test B
  }

  // Just return 'undefined' if both of the test already have 50 occurences each.
  return;
}
```

The "getNumberOfOccurencesOfTestA" and "getNumberOfOccurencesOfTestB" are functions that look in a variable that keeps the state of the number occurences of test A and test B occuring respectivelly, it can be a global variable, a database, a file etc.